# Why does acceleration seem not to be the gradient of gravitational potential?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, potential-energy, gauss-law

Consider a spherically symmetric distribution of density $\rho(r)$.  We can define the mass enclosed within each radius $r$ using $\frac{dM(r)}{dr} = 4\pi r^2 \rho(r)$, with the condition that $M(r=0) = 0$.

The gravitational acceleration and potential can then be given as,

$$\begin{align}
a_g &= -\frac{GM}{r^2}\\
\Phi_g &= -\frac{GM}{r}.
\end{align}$$

But then the acceleration wouldn't seem to be the gradient of the potential!

$$a_g = - \frac{GM}{r^2} \neq -\nabla \Phi_g = \frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{GM(r)}{r}\right).$$

What am I missing?

---

This comes up, for example when writing the equations of stellar structure, or the Lane-Emden equations.  I've seen these written as both,

$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dP}{dr} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$, and as
$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dP}{dr} = -\nabla \Phi_g$

for example, the [Wikipedia article on Lane-Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation#From_hydrostatic_equilibrium) includes both of these expressions.  This seems to suggest that $\Phi_g \neq \frac{GM(r)}{r}$...

Comment: I suspect that the potential in the linked article on Lane-Emden is not literally the gravitational potential, but rather is an effective potential that can be used to describe that type of system.

Comment: @Dave: I started reading the Lane-Emden artice, and the potential $\Phi$ used there does appear to be the gravitational potential. In essence, Lane-Emden is just the combination of Laplace's equation $\Delta\Phi=4\pi G\rho$ (which is universally valid), Newton's law $-\rho\nabla\Phi=\nabla P$ (which is valid in a gravitating fluid), the polytropic constitutive relation $P=C\rho^k$ (which is an approximation), and spherical symmetry. The polytropic assumption allows you to eliminate $P$, resulting in a differential equation solely in $\rho$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your expression for the potential $\Phi(r)$ is incorrect. The expression
$\Phi(r) = -\frac{GM(r)}{r}$ is only valid outside the sphere.

As an explicit demonstration of its invalidity, note that
$$\underset{r\rightarrow0}{\text{lim}}\,\Phi(r)=\underset{r\rightarrow0}{\text{lim}}\,\left[-\frac{G}{r}\int_0^r4\pi r'^2\rho(r')\,dr'\right]=0$$
assuming that $\rho(r)$ is finite. In particular, this also predicts that $\Phi(0)=0$ for a uniform-density sphere. However, for a uniform density sphere, [we actually have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#Spherical_symmetry) $\Phi(0)=-2\pi G\rho R^2$ (using the convention $\Phi(\infty)=0$).

#### Actual Potential Inside Distribution

The gravitational potential $\Phi_r(a)$ at radius $a$ due to a [thin spherical shell](http://terra.rice.edu/department/faculty/niu/ESCI324/09-ESCI324-Gravity.pdf) of radius $r$ with surface density $\rho(r)$ is

$$\Phi_r(a)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&-\frac{4\pi G r^2\rho(r)}{a} &&: a>r\\
&-4\pi G \rho(r) r &&: a\leq r
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

and thus the correct expression for the potential due to an arbitrary spherically-symmetric charge distribution $\rho(r)$ becomes

$$\Phi(a)=\int_0^\infty\Phi_r(a)\,dr.$$

If $\rho(r)=0$ for all $r\geq R$, then we can rewrite the integral as
$$\Phi(a)=\int_0^R\Phi_r(a)\,dr=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^R-\frac{4\pi G r^2\rho(r)}{a}\,dr &&: a>r\\
&\int_0^a-\frac{4\pi G r^2\rho(r)}{a}\,dr+\int_a^R-4\pi G \rho(r) r\,dr &&: a\leq r
\end{aligned}
\right.
\\
=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&-\frac{GM(R)}{a} &&: a>r\\
&-\frac{GM(a)}{a}+\int_a^R-4\pi G \rho(r) r\,dr &&: a\leq r
\end{aligned}
\right..$$

In essence, your expression for potential was missing the term $\int_a^R-4\pi G \rho(r) r\,dr$, which caused the errors you saw.

#### Finally, answering your question

We then compute the gradient, $\nabla\Phi(a)$, using the $a\leq R$ case for $\Phi$ listed above. In Mathematica this easily becomes:

```
-D[Integrate[-((4*G*Pi*r^2*\[Rho][r])/a), {r, 0, a}] + 
  Integrate[-4*G*Pi*r*\[Rho][r], 
       {r, a, R}], a]//TeXForm
```

yielding
$$a_g(a)=-\nabla\Phi(a)=-\int_0^a \frac{4 \pi  G r^2 \rho (r)}{a^2} \, dr=-\frac{GM(a)}{a^2},$$
exactly as you wanted.

#### Lane-Emden in a nutshell

In essence, Lane-Emden is just the combination of Poisson's equation $\Delta\Phi=4\pi G\rho$ (which is universally valid), Newton's law $\rho\nabla\Phi=\nabla P$ (which is valid in a gravitating fluid), the polytropic constitutive relation $P=C\rho^k$ (which is an approximation), and spherical symmetry. The polytropic assumption allows you to eliminate $P$, resulting in a differential equation solely in $\rho$.

(Minor note: Lane-Emden is commonly expressed in a dimensionless parameter $\theta$, rather than $\rho$ itself.)

Comment: Interesting.  This makes a lot of sense.  So, to find the potential I ***must*** integrate in from infinity?

Comment: @zhermes: You can integrate from anywhere in theory, you just have to be careful. I suspect that the key misunderstanding you have is the following: given a hollow sphere, what is the potential inside? The answer is **not** zero. In particular, the expression $\Phi(r)=-GM(r)/r$ predicts a zero potential inside of a thin hollow shell of radius $R$ (since there is no mass for $r<R$). But this is wrong. In essence, the shell theorem only says that forces due to spherically symmetric matter outside the current radius are 0. It does **not** say that the potential due to outside matter is zero.

Comment: You can shift around the zero of a potential function all you want, so this argument is unconvincing.

Comment: @zhermes Potential *differences* can be integrated from anywhere. To get the potential directly from the integral without a correction term you integrate it from where it is defined. In the case of the usual gravitational potential that definition is zero at infinite remove.

Comment: @Dave: You can shift the zero, but the definition of potential for a uniform density sphere that I cited uses the convention $\Phi(\infty)=0$. Since the OP's function also satisfies $\Phi(\infty)=0$, if it is correct, then it will also reproduce the statement $\Phi(0)=-2\pi G\rho R^2$. However, it does not, instead satisfying $\Phi(0)=0$. Therefore, the OP's expression for $\Phi$ must be incorrect. Is that convincing? I can edit my answer to include this additional subtlety if you think it makes it clearer.

Comment: @Dave: I edited the answer to make things clearer and show the correct expression for potential from an arbitrary distribution; does it seem more transparent? Apologies for initially neglecting to mention the $\Phi(\infty)=0$ convention in my first edit.